# Should our claim ever be the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I recently read the following regarding the null and alternative hypotheses:

> If the original claim includes equality $\left(\le, =, \text{or} \ge\right)$, it is the null hypothesis. If the original claim does not include equality $\left(<, \ne, >\right)$ then the null hypothesis is the complement of the original claim. The null hypothesis always includes the equal sign.

I was until now under the impression that our original claim was always the alternative hypothesis. I thought it was insufficient to merely fail to reject our claim – we need to actively have enough evidence to reject the null and accept our claim.

I do agree that have a non-closed set (say, $\mu < \mu_0$)  as our null can occasionally be misleading, and is in most cases equivalent to have a closed set ($\mu \le \mu_0$). But, does this really mean we should define the null & alternative hypothesis solely based on the equality sign?

Comment: Adding the source for the exact claim: [these course notes](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch09-def.html).

Comment: I would abandon those notes because they are incorrect and misleading.

Comment: @whuber could you elaborate on what's wrong with the notes?

Comment: Each of the five statements in the description of the null hypothesis is misleading and wrong.  They mislead by suggesting an examination of inequalities is a useful or correct way to identify a null hypothesis.  They are wrong by supplying invalid recommendations: there are common, important exceptions to everything recommended in those notes.  They are also ambiguous by not explaining or defining nonstandard (but crucial terms) such as "original claim."

Comment: It is possible to make a claim based on the null hypothesis, but they would be based on the statistcal power of the test.  ISTR there is a statistical term for that sort of testing, but I can't recall what it is.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial [Equivalence testing?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test)

Comment: @Dave, that isn't the one I had in mind, but certainly seems relevant to the question.  The example I had in mind was that climate skeptics often point out the lack of statistical warming since [cherrypicked start date] as evidence against climate change.  However the period is invariably too short for a failure to reject the null to be meaningful.  If they had a period long enough to have high statistical power, their argument would have some value.  So this isn't arguing for/against equivalence, but explicitly for H0 as the aim of the test.

Comment: So in that case, you can construct an argument where you are arguing **for** the null, but evaluating the power of the test is often quite tricky, which is why it is normally much better to have a "devils advocate" null hypothesis, which opposes the thing you are arguing for.  Unfortunately a lot of people adopt the "null ritual" and think that H0 **has** to be an assumption of no difference.

Comment: From the notes mentioned above by @AryaMcCarthy: "Null Hypothesis ( H0 ) Statement of zero or no change." oh dear... https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053535704000927 Fullly agree with whuber!